# How to block network connection to all `root` process?

Tags: networking, nftables

My system is debian 10 with nftables.
output of `nethogs` as below:

```
? root     192.168.2.10:59100-172.217.27.138:443 
? root     192.168.2.10:59086-172.217.27.138:443 
? root     192.168.2.10:59082-172.217.27.138:443 
? root     192.168.2.10:59062-172.217.27.138:443 
? root     192.168.2.10:59058-172.217.27.138:443 
? root     192.168.2.10:59054-172.217.27.138:443 
? root     192.168.2.10:59030-172.217.27.138:443 
? root     192.168.2.10:59026-172.217.27.138:443
? root     192.168.2.10:42314-27.19.249.194:443  
? root     192.168.2.10:49788-216.58.200.234:443
```

I `ss -pl | grep 59100` but got nothing,then I plan to block all `root` process to  network connection.
How to do it?

Comment: This seems like *an XY problem*. If I get it right, you don't understand what these connections are and try to solve it simply by blocking them. But there's a problem with this approach: root might need Internet access for e.g. system updates, and if there are malicious connections from root, it's already game over.

Comment: @EsaJokinen,I want to block root all the time,except update.

Answer (score 2):

With **iptables**, this would be rather easy with the *`owner` [match extension](https://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html)*:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p all -m owner --uid-owner 0 -j DROP
```

Likewise, **nftables** has [matching by socket UID / GID](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Matching_packet_metainformation#Matching_by_socket_UID_.2F_GID):

```
sudo nft add rule filter output meta skuid 0 counter
```

Comment: I add `log prefix "drop root: "  meta skuid 0 counter drop` in nftables rule,seemed works fine. ps.What's the meaning of `meta`?

Comment: Cound I use `!` or `not` to set only one user pass,such as `log prefix "drop root: "  meta  ! skuid 1000 counter drop`?